# Square roots not on same height

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

This part `C\frac{1}{\sqrt{G}}\sqrt{\rho}` doesn't seem to be on the same height as this part `\sqrt{b}\sqrt{l}` when compiled. What am I doing wrong?

```
\begin{flalign*}
T=C\frac{1}{\sqrt{G}}\sqrt{\rho}\sqrt{b}\sqrt{l} &&
\end{flalign*}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong, you're just wanting something that is not the default. The reason for the different `\sqrt`s is because `\rho` and `b` (and `l`) have different height and depth, which `\sqrt` accommodates.

Here are some alternatives (non-exhaustive) that tried to show you what is possible:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
  T &= C\frac{1}{\sqrt{G}}\sqrt{\rho}\sqrt{b}\sqrt{l} \\
  T &= C\frac{1}{\sqrt{G}}\sqrt{\vphantom{b}\rho}\sqrt{b}\sqrt{l} \\
  T &= C\frac{1}{\sqrt{G}}\sqrt{\mathrlap{\smash{\mkern-2mu\rho}}\phantom{b}}\sqrt{b}\sqrt{l} \\
  T &= C\frac{1}{\sqrt{G}}\sqrt{\vphantom{b}\mkern-2mu\rho\mkern2mu}\sqrt{b}\sqrt{l} \\
  T &= C\frac{1}{\sqrt{G}}\sqrt{\rho b l} \\
  T &= C\frac{1}{\sqrt{G}}\sqrt{\rho\,b\,l} \\
  T &= C\frac{1}{\sqrt{G}}\sqrt{\mkern-2mu\rho\,b\,l}
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

Options include

- horizontal adjustment of `\rho` using `\mkern` (`m`ath `kern`ing);
- removal of depth (and height) using `\smash`;
- vertical struts using `\vphantom`;
- overlapping (`math` `r`ight over`lap`) with `\phantom` content to provide similar horizontal spacing/placement.

*Many* other options also exist, including moving `\sqrt{rho}` to form part of the `\frac`.

Answer (score 8):

Don't use `flalign` for left aligning displays; this is a job for the `fleqn` option.

The problem is that a lonely `\sqrt{\rho}` shouldn't have too much space between the bar and the rho, but this obviously gives asymmetric results when square roots appear together like in

```
$\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$
```

There are several tricks for equalizing square root symbols, each with its pros and its cons.

A couple of adjustments are to be made anyway: the `\rho` under the square root should be backspaced a little, to avoid a hole; between two consecutive square roots a thin space should be added.

In order to solve the main problem, two strategies are possible: the first one is easier, as it consists in adding `\mathstrut` under the square roots; the second strategy is to remove the depth from `\rho` and adding a phantom `b`.

Which one to choose depends on many factors; leave these decisions to the final revision of your document. A change in notation might make obsolete one of these constructions.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example
\begin{document}
\lipsum*[2]
\[
T=C\frac{1}{\sqrt{G}}\sqrt{\!\rho\mathstrut}\,\sqrt{b\mathstrut}\,\sqrt{l\mathstrut}
\]
\lipsum*[2]
\[
T=C\frac{1}{\sqrt{G}}
  \vphantom{\rho}\sqrt{\!\smash[b]{\rho}\vphantom{b}}\,\sqrt{b}\,\sqrt{l}
\]
\lipsum*[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]