# Why are two radicals set at different heights?

Tags: math-mode, baseline, radicals

In typesetting the following in a,

```
\sqrt[n]{a \cdot b} = \sqrt[n]{a} \cdot \sqrt[n]{b}
```

… the second radical is being typeset higher than the first:

[image]

Why? And how can I fix it?

> MWE:
>
> ```
> \documentclass[12pt]{article}
>
> \begin{document}
>
> \begin{displaymath}
> \sqrt[n]{a \cdot b} = \sqrt[n]{a} \cdot \sqrt[n]{b}
> \end{displaymath}
>
> \end{document}
> ```

Comment: perhaps helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148282/square-roots-not-on-same-height

Comment: @cmhughes To me, it appears like a duplicate. ELLIOTTCABLE, please, is the question linked in the above comment what you are looking for? If so, we can mark your question as a duplicate.

Comment: Ahhh, the taller ascender on the `b`! Yes, that answers my question (in fact, @egreg's answer literally uses my problem as an example!), although it's very unintuitive behaviour  — thanks, @cmhughes. Feel free to mark-as-dup.